# How can I use writeMat Function

Tags: r, matlab

I am trying to use the function writeMat from the R.matlab.
on a matrix
like that:

```
writeMat('C:/Users/nirgalun/Desktop/soojin/coor_cpg_matrix.mat',coor_cpg_matrix)
```

I get the error:

```
[2018-10-07 13:54:07] Exception: Detected non-named objects. Non-named objects will not be available in MATLAB if completed. Use writeMat(..., x=a, y=y) and not writeMat(..., x=a, y): writeMat.default("C:/Users/nirgalun/Desktop/soojin/coor_cpg_matrix.mat", , Detected non-named objects. Non-named objects will not be available in MATLAB if completed. Use writeMat(..., x=a, y=y) and not writeMat(..., x=a, y):     coor_cpg_matrix)

  at #02. writeMat.default("C:/Users/nirgalun/Desktop/soojin/coor_cpg_matrix.mat", 
              coor_cpg_matrix)
          - writeMat.default() is in environment 'R.matlab'

  at #01. writeMat("C:/Users/nirgalun/Desktop/soojin/coor_cpg_matrix.mat", 
              coor_cpg_matrix)
          - writeMat() is in environment 'R.matlab'

Error: Detected non-named objects. Non-named objects will not be available in MATLAB if completed. Use writeMat(..., x=a, y=y) and not writeMat(..., x=a, y): writeMat.default("C:/Users/nirgalun/Desktop/soojin/coor_cpg_matrix.mat", , Detected non-named objects. Non-named objects will not be available in MATLAB if completed. Use writeMat(..., x=a, y=y) and not writeMat(..., x=a, y):     coor_cpg_matrix)
```

How can I overcome that?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message and doc says, the argument must be named:

```
writeMat('C:/Users/nirgalun/Desktop/soojin/coor_cpg_matrix.mat',coor_cpg_matrix = coor_cpg_matrix)
```